# java throwing exception without catching it?

Tags: java, exception

Is it possible to throw an exception without catching it?

Example

```
public void foo() throws SomeException{
    // ....
    if (somethingCatestrophic) throw new SomeException();
    // ....
}
```

Now I want to call foo, but don't want to catch any errors, as the exceptions should never been thrown at runtime (unless there's a bug)

Comment: is there any reason you don't want to catch it? If it's performance, as far as I'm aware it's not much difference going through a try-catch block UNLESS the exception is actually thrown, then there is plenty of overhead. But if the error is catastrophic

Comment: No, because the error is not suppose to happen (i.e. programming error, or runtimeexceptions).

Comment: Whoops, posted the above before finishing. Well errors are never 'suppose' to happen! But it sounds like you are throwing the error for the sake of it. I thinkyou need to rethink whether you want to be throwing the error in the first place

Comment: For debugging purposes. Example is that wrong argument format, or something like that (such as a negative height or a negative weight)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Unless it is something you are planning for and recovering from locally, it is probably best in this case to use an unchecked exception, e.g., a `RuntimeException` derivative.

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful for writing non-optimistic code, where I can have an exception that SHOULD never happen but is there to let another developer know that they forgot something in their code.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid catching an exception, but if there is an exception thrown and you don't catch it your program will cease execution (crash).

There is no way to **ignore** an exception. If your app doesn't need to do anything in response to a given exception, then you would simply catch it, and then do nothing.

```
try {
  ...some code that throws an exception...
} catch (SomeException ex) {
  // do nothing
}
```

NOTE: This is often considered bad style, however, and people may tell you so. The often-cited reason is that, even if you're not going to do anything with the exception, that in most cases you should at least log it somewhere, notify the user, or take some other appropriate action depending on what you app is doing, and what caused the exception in the first place. If you're not sure why an exception is being thrown (maybe it's a bug you haven't solved yet), then generally you should at least log it so you can figure it out later.

Comment: Turns out what I needed was RuntimeException, as the error is never suppose to happen (the exception should never been thrown unless there's a bug in the code), which I completely forgot about

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you catch it inside the method?

Simply use try catch block and go on, if the exception is insignificant and doesn't influence any behaviour of your program.

Comment: Yeah, forgot about RuntimeException completely. (In python mode.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick, You can play with generics.

```
/**
 * A java syntax glitch to throw any throwable without the need to catch it.
 *
 * @param throwable to be ignite
 * @param <T>       the type of the throwable to trick the compiler that it's the one thrown
 * @throws T exactly the given throwable
 */
public static <T extends Throwable> void ignite(Throwable throwable) throws T {
    Objects.requireNonNull(throwable, "throwable");
    throw (T) throwable;
}
```

This test should pass

```
@Test(expected = IOException.class)
public void ignite() {
    ignite(new IOException());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `SomeException` is a checked exception, the method that calls `foo()` will either have to catch that exception and deal with it or also be declared to throw `SomeException` or a parent of it.

If `SomeException` is a runtime exception, then methods that call it will not need to catch it.